# Detecting whether screen is off or on inside service

Tags: android

I'm developing an application where I need to pause an activity when screen is off and when screen is on, it must be resumed.

I want the detection to be done inside the service. I have used startservice() to start up my service. But don't know where to put the following code:

```
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isScreenOn())
    MyActivity.onResume();
else
    MyActivity.onPause();
```

I tried googling around but I couldn't find it.

Comment: This happens to an Activity by default, any Activity in Android is paused when the screen goes off and is resumed when the screen is on again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a BroadcastReceiver. Declare it in the service:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new myReceiver();
```

In your service onCreate:

```
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

In your service onDestroy:

```
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Create the receiver:

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //Do something when the screen goes off
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            //Do something when it's back on
        }
    }
```

Anyway, keep in mind that the activities by default goes onPause and back onResume when the screen goes off/on